# Deleting a class using ant tool

Tags: deployment

Deleting a class using ant tool(destructiveChanges.xml) in salesforce giving an `UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION.`
Below is the exception details for the same.

> Failed to proces the request successfully. Cause(UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION):
>   UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An une pected error occurred. Please include this
>   ErrorId if you contact support: 1508 82246-8554 (451778203)

Amrish

Comment: I'd consider contacting support with the ErrorId. Without more details it's going to be hard for any of us to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Sometimes this error doesn't persist. Did you tried several times?

Comment: If you want to diagnose the problem then several days working with Salesforce support is the only way to go; those error numbers allow support to find more detailed logs about the problem. But if you just want to move on, I suggest trying to delete the class manually to see if that gives any more information.

Comment: I have tried it so many times but still getting the same error. I have tried with another option using Eclise IDE and it works, file is getting deleted from target org. But i want to know how can we delete a class using ANT tool

Comment: OK. Post your destructiveChanges.xml and as much other relevant information as possible and someone may see something you are doing that is causing the internal Salesforce error that can be fixed in your code.

Comment: Below is the code in destructiveChanges.xml file                                         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
<members>testClsChange</members>
<name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
</Package>